# My Discord bot returns an error when I want it to send reddit memes. How do I fix this?

Tags: python, discord, reddit, praw

I wrote a code for a Discord bot so that it could send memes from the meme sub reddit but whenever I try it, it doesn't work. Here is the code:

```
 import Discord
 import praw
 reddit = praw.Reddit(client_id='#',
                 client_secret='#',
                 user_agent='Discord bot')
 async def meme():
     for submission in reddit.subreddit('memes').hot():
         print(submission.title)
 if message.content.startswith('Plz meme'):
     memes = meme()
     await message.channel.send(memes)
```

The error I get is "RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'meme' was never awaited
await coro(*args, **kwargs)
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback"

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Well, did you try putting `coroutine was never awaited` into a search engine? What happened then?

Comment: Why is `meme` a coroutine in the first place? It never `await`s anything. What do you think the `async` keyword preceding `def` means?

Comment: You should probably not put `client_secret` in the post

Comment: @AbdurrahmanA I recommend you change your client id and secret as soon as possible, since you have now published them for the world to see.

Answer (score 1):

Well you have never made your async function `meme` to `await`. There are two simple fixes to this question, either replace `async def meme():` in line 6 to `def meme()` or add `await` before calling the function `meme()` in line 10.

```
import Discord
import praw
reddit = praw.Reddit(client_id='',
                 client_secret='',
                 user_agent='')
async def meme():
    for submission in reddit.subreddit('memes').hot():
        print(submission.title)
if message.content.startswith('Plz meme'):
    memes = await meme()
    await message.channel.send(memes)
```

Another suggestion is using `apraw` instead of `praw` with discord bot.

```
import apraw

reddit = apraw.Reddit(client_id="",
                      client_secret="",
                      username="",
                      password="",
                      user_agent=""
)

async def get_meme():

    subreddit = await reddit.subreddit("memes")

    meme_lst = []
    async for subm in subreddit.hot(limit=500):
        meme_lst.append(subm)

    return meme_lst

@bot.command()
async def meme(self, ctx):

    meme_lst = await get_meme()

    rand = random.choice(meme_lst)

    em = discord.Embed(title=rand.title)
    em.set_image(url=rand.url)

    await ctx.send(embed=em)
```

**References:**
[apraw](https://apraw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)